# What, if anything, does higher category theory have to say about situations where each subcategory induces a sub-$2$-category?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $\mathbf{Top}$ denote the $2$-category of topological spaces, continuous mappings, and homotopies between them. Let $\mathbf{C}$ denote a wide subcategory of $\mathbf{Top}$. Then we get a wide sub-$2$-category $\overline{\mathbf{C}}$ of $\mathbf{Top}$ as follows. Firstly, the underlying category of $\overline{\mathbf{C}}$ is just $\mathbf{C}$. Secondly, the $2$-cells are precisely those homotopies between $\mathbf{C}$-arrows that "remain" in $\mathbf{C}$ through the entire deformation process. For example, if $\mathbf{C}$ is the wide subcategory of $\mathbf{Top}$ where the morphisms are injective continuous functions, then a $\mathbf{C}$-morphism $X \rightarrow Y$ is an "$X$-shaped" knot in the space $Y$, and the $2$-cells of $\overline{\mathbf{C}}$ are "witnesses" that two knots are equivalent. Take $X$ to be the circle and $Y$ to be $\mathbb{R}^3$ to recover the usual definitions.

> **Question.** What, if anything, does higher category theory have to say about $2$-categories $\mathbf{T}$ equipped with a special way of extending each subcategory $\mathbf{C}$ into a sub-$2$-category $\overline{\mathbf{C}}$?
>
> E.g. What are the appropriate axioms, definitions, terms and phrases, generalizations, etc.

Comment: Do you have any example where a wide subcategory of a 2-category is not the underlying category of a sub-2-category? (I mean, can't you just restrict to identity 2-cells?)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, don't quite follow. Can you say it in different words?

Comment: Does there exist a 2-category $\mathbf{D}$ and a wide sub-1-category $\mathsf{C} \subset \mathbf{D}$ such that there does not exist a sub-2-category $\bar{\mathsf{C}} \subset \mathbf{D}$ with underlying 1-category (when you forget all 2-cells) $\mathsf{C}$? Maybe I misunderstood your question? What do you mean by "a subcategory induces a sub-2-category"?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, have you read the whole question?

Comment: No, I didn't read either the question nor the title, I just typed random words... What the hell kind of question is that? The word "induces" appears only once in your question and isn't defined. Instead of assuming I didn't read your question, perhaps consider that it may not be as clear as possible. Have a good day.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, it should be a little clearer now. But if you have read the *whole* question, not just the highlighted bit, it should be pretty clear what it is that I'm after.

Comment: So you don't see the difference between "Each sub-thing induces **a** widget" and "The whole collection of sub-things is equipped with a way of associating a widget induced by every sub-thing"? It seems to me that precision is important. Since I can't read your mind, I don't know if you're interested in the former or the latter, even with the first paragraph, since the question was formulated differently. I've removed my vote to close as unclear, anyway.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, we seem to have a tendency to talk past each other unfortunately, but if I've understood you correctly, you're essentially saying that its important to distinguish between situations where we have a distinguished mapping $\mathbf{C} \mapsto \overline{\mathbf{C}},$ as distinct from a "mere existence statement." If so, then yes, I completely agree, and that aspect of my question wasn't very clear originally.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, wait, so are you saying that its *still* completely unclear what I'm asking? If so, can you point to the parts that are causing this?

Comment: No, I have removed my vote to close as unclear, which means I no longer find the question unclear.

Comment: My impression is that your construction depends on more than just the abstract 2-category Top. You need to know that the 2-morphisms are defined using an interval object, namely $[0, 1]$.